# Remove HTML tags and its content based on ID with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

- I would like to remove some HTML tags and its content from a HTML file based on the id/class's html element.
- The tag itself doesn't matter.

Here's my code in PHP :

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("assets/page.html");
$removeTagsbyID = ['button' , 'navbar'];
foreach ($removeTagsbyID as $removeTagbyID) {
    $pattern = "#<(.*?)$removeTagbyID(.*?)>#is";
    $homepage = preg_replace($pattern, '', $homepage);
}
```

For example if my array contains the id "navbar",

```
<div id="top-bar"><div id="navbar">Content</div></div>
```

It should give :

```
<div id="top-bar"></div>
```

Comment: try [simpledomparser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) or  [phpdom](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHPs inbuilt [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) and [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) objects to parse and process HTML:

```
function removeTagsByID($html, $ids) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    // find element with specified ID values
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $tags = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']");
        // and remove them
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
        }
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}

$html = '<div id="top-bar"><div id="navbar">Content</div></div>';
echo removeTagsByID($html, ['button' , 'navbar']);
```

Output

```
<div id="top-bar"></div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1uM8b)

Comment: Note that since OP said that the "tag itself doesn't matter", `//*[@id='$id']` would probably be more appropriate. Otherwise, upvoted.

Comment: @Jeto good point. Updated. And thanks...

Comment: You're welcome :)